# migration script sql server for inserting an item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an Migration Script but i need some help:, i had the very basic script to insert an item into a table but i am trying to do it in a way to check for the item first if it exists, then insert it else skip it

here is my code:

```
use mydatabase;

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT '3','test1','test3/abc.html';
```

Comment: You need an identifier to tell if the record exists or not, what field is that in your script?

Comment: you can try to use `Merge` or `DML trigger`

Comment: Another way: you can make the three columns unique with an index/constraint and set WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT '3','test1','test3/abc.html'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 
                  FROM dbo.mytable
                  WHERE col1='3' 
                  AND col2='test1' 
                  AND col3='test3/abc.html'
                 )
```

You can change the where depending on what you consider already inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to repeat the expression just use `value` construct like that :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
FROM (values (3, 'test1','test3/abc.html')) t (col1, col2, col3)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 
                  FROM dbo.mytable m
                  WHERE m.col1 = t.col1 
                  AND m.col2 = t.col2 
                  AND m.col3 = t.col3
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (but you would need some kind of key to identify if the record exists or not) -

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.mytable WHERE col1 = '3' AND col2 = 'test1' AND col3 = 'test3/abc.html')
BEGIN
insert into dbo.mytable(col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT '3','test1','test3/abc.html'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MERGE:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (col1 nvarchar(20), col2 nvarchar(20), col3 nvarchar(20))

INSERT INTO #mytable(col1,col2,col3) 
SELECT '3','test1','test3/abc.html';

Merge #mytable t
USING (SELECT '3','test1','test3/abc.html') s (col1, col2, col3)
ON t.col1 = s.col1 
AND t.col2 = s.col2 
AND t.col3 = s.col3
when not matched by target then
    INSERT  (col1,col2,col3)  VALUES (s.col1, s.col2, s.col3);
```